# How to select person depending on one to many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table person

```
create table Person  (
  id SERIAL not null,
  ...
);
```

person can have 0 or more PreviousName

```
create table PreviousName  (
  id       SERIAL    not null,
  person_id INTEGER  not null,
  value     VARCHAR(120)   
);
```

how can I select all person who has for example value in previous name "John"

Comment: Your question is to broad. Please be more specific.

Comment: Please define "previous" name? Show some sample data and the expected output (as formatted text, not as a picture). Ideally create a http://sqlfiddle.com example

Comment: sorry copy paste table name. PreviousName is another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Person
where id in (select person_id from PREDCHOZI_JM_PR 
             where value = 'John')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand your question ...

```
  SELECT * FROM Person LEFT JOIN PREDCHOZI_JM_PR ON person.id=PREDCHOZI_JM_PR.person_id 
  WHERE value="John"
```

Comment: `"JOHN"` is a column name in SQL, not a string literal.

Comment: No point doing an outer join when having right table conditions in the where clause.

Comment: Isn't it slower to have a nested SELECT than Left Join?

Comment: @slek: no not necessarily for a DBMS with a decent optimizer (and a JOIN and a sub-select might return different results)

Answer (score 0):

You can find distinct person_id from PREDCHOZI_JM_PR with value containing john:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT person_id FROM PREDCHOZI_JM_PR WHERE value LIKE '%John%')
```

Comment: With IN duplicates make no difference. I.e. DISTINCT makes no sense here.

Comment: @jarlh of course it will not make any difference if there are less rows in table PREDCHOZI_JM_PR but if same table will contain million rows than it will make difference in performance

Comment: You may be correct, I don't know postgresql optimization.